# How do you run the meteor tests?

Tags: meteor

I made some changes to livedata and would like to run the livedata_test. How do you use tinytest to run the livedata_test?

Answer (score 8):

After doing some digging, I've figured out that you may run meteor from the packages directory of your cloned meteor source.

Source: [SFJS #23: Functional Programming and Meteor.js](http://youtu.be/HAcN3JyQoyY?t=1h36m56s) (this is actually a fantastic video in general).

1. Switch to `... /meteor/packages/`
2. Run `meteor`
3. Navigate to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/` in the browser.

Tests for individual packages may be run by navigating to the specific package directory and following steps 2 and 3 above.

Presto:
[image: meteor test suite]

Comment: What was the error? Though I had not played with Meteor in a while, if you were to provide more constructive comments/criticism, you might get a more solid reply and additional information - even if it's not from me ;)

Comment: The video is private. Is it available somewhere else ?

Comment: This is no longer accurate. `You're not in a Meteor project directory.`

Answer (score 6):

Might be worth nothing that you need to make sure you are running the dev "meteor" script from your working git directory. Simply running meteor will default to the system meteor in your path (if you have meteor installed) and will not pick up any changes to the tests / core code that you make.

Answer (score 4):

Run `meteor test-packages`, then point your browser at `http://localhost:3000` .

Answer (score 2):

Run meteor from in the directory of the package you want to test and view results in browser.

Answer (score 2):

Velocity had been selected as the official testing framework for meteor 1.0. The announcement has been made in the [last meteor devshop (june 2014)](http://youtu.be/kwFv1mXrLWE?t=40m50s).

Packages developed with velocity:

- [velocity](https://atmospherejs.com/package/velocity) (the test runner)
- [jasmine-unit](https://atmospherejs.com/package/jasmine-unit) (jasmine syntax)
- [mocha-web-velocity](https://atmospherejs.com/package/mocha-web-velocity) (for testing collections)
- [velocity-html-reporter](https://atmospherejs.com/package/velocity-html-reporter) (view the tests in the browser)

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone git://github.com/meteor/meteor.git
cd meteor
./meteor test-packages <package>
```

Then navigate to http://localhost:3000/.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass it a driver package. This is how I ran them:

`meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha`

Then check out the app and you should see a UI with the test results.